# RestKit direct foregin key mapping

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, foreign-keys, restkit

I have the following JSON

```
{
   ...
   "users": [
            {
                "name": "Username 1"
                "id": "uid1",
            },
            {
                "name": "Username 2",
                "id": "uid2",                
                "userCreator": "uid1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Username 3",
                "id": "uid3",
                "userCreator": "uid1"
            }
        ]
}
```

And in CoreData, in the User class (properties named id, name) i have a one to many relationship named userCreator with class User

Now i need to map the JSON relationship, i tried

```
RKManagedObjectMapping * mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class] inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultObjectStore]];

mapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"id";
[mapping mapAttributes:@"id", @"name", nil];

RKManagedObjectMapping * userCreatorMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class] inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultObjectStore]];
userCreatorMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"id";
[userCreatorMapping mapAttributes:@"id", nil];

//[mapping hasOne:@"userCreator" withMapping:userCreatorMapping];
[mapping mapRelationship:@"userCreator" withMapping:userCreatorMapping];
[mapping connectRelationship:@"userCreator" withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"id"];
```

Which doesnt work right, producing

```
...
"users":[{
             "id":"uid1",
             "name":"Username 1"
         },
         {
             "id":"uid2",
             "name":"Username 2",
             "userCreator":{"id":"uid1"} // wanted "userCreator":"uid1",
         }...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the offending lines are

```
userCreatorMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"id";
// ...
[mapping connectRelationship:@"userCreator" 
     withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:@"id"];
```

While I do not use RK, it seems obvious that you are not telling the userCreatorMapping what to map to what. You are just giving it `"id"` on both sides.

Comment: i thing the setup is correct, i map object inside userCreator to attribute id, which is set as the primary attribute, the object in userCreator, is just a string, which represents the id

Comment: Then you have to drop the mapping altogether. You will then just get the string.